# Import XML Google Spreadsheet - Help me with PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I came across a requirement to import my DB-Users to a google-spreadsheet.

I did a code with the help of the below instruction.
http://www.distilled.net/blog/distilled/guide-to-google-docs-importxml/#chapter4

Now i can get all my DB-Users using the below code.

```
=importxml("http://mydomain.com/v5/admin/export_google.php","//tr")
```

If i paste the above code in a google spreadsheet i can see all my DB-Users in my spreadsheet.

Now, as far as security is concerned

http://mydomain.com/v5/admin/export_google.php  -> If i type this url in my browser, then i can see all the db-users.

I need this file to be password protected. Only my client having the code to import the db-users can view my db-users.

Is there a way to keep the file password protected(export_google.php). I know, i can set a username and password at top of my php file but doing that will it won't work if i paste the code in google spreadsheet.

Could someone help me out.

In other words - my client having the code i.e. =importxml("http://mydomain.com/v5/admin/export_google.php","//tr") can take the db-users in google-spreadsheet. Others should not get the information of my db-users using the php file.

Comment: What has this got to do with appengine

Comment: @TimHoffman - There is nothing to do with app engine. Just asked whether there is a way to sought out my question. Understand?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add some GET var to your request and check it inside your script.
Like so:

```
=importxml("http://example.com/v5/admin/export_google.php?pass=mypass","//tr")
```

And inside PHP script:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['pass']) && $_REQUEST['pass'] == 'mypass') {
  // your code here
}
```